# Sublime text 3 theme edit colors not working

Tags: sublimetext3

I have set in my ST3, the Twilight theme, but i want to edit some tags (img, form, a, ...) with different colors.

This is what i have in my theme code:

```
<dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>html: table tags</string>
                <key>scope</key>
                <string>entity.name.tag.table.html,entity.table.attribute-name.cfml,meta.tag.inline.table.html</string>
                <key>settings</key>
                <dict>
                     <key>fontStyle</key>
                     <string></string>
                     <key>foreground</key>
                     <string>#009999</string>
                </dict>
           </dict>

           <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>html: img tags</string>
                <key>scope</key>
                <string>entity.name.tag.img.html,entity.img.attribute-name.cfml,meta.tag.inline.img.html,meta.tag.block.object.html</string>
                <key>settings</key>
                <dict>
                     <key>fontStyle</key>
                     <string></string>
                     <key>foreground</key>
                     <string>#990099</string>
                </dict>
           </dict>

           <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>html: form tags</string>
                <key>scope</key>
                <string>entity.name.tag.form.html,entity.form.attribute-name.cfml,meta.tag.inline.form.html,meta.tag.block.form.html</string>
                <key>settings</key>
                <dict>
                     <key>fontStyle</key>
                     <string></string>
                     <key>foreground</key>
                     <string>#ff9900</string>
                </dict>
           </dict>

           <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>html: anchor tags</string>
                <key>scope</key>
                <string>entity.name.tag.link.html,entity.link.attribute-name.cfml,meta.tag.inline.link.html</string>
                <key>settings</key>
                <dict>
                     <key>fontStyle</key>
                     <string></string>
                     <key>foreground</key>
                     <string>#008000</string>
                </dict>
           </dict>
```

But the colors dont change. Table tag should be one color, img other, a other.
[image]

Is there another file to edit?

Comment: How is this helping me?

Comment: thats the best color theme in ST

Comment: Has the same problem, all the tags are the same color...I edited the monokai (added the code for img, tabel, form) and the same...